# Python cannot recognize data type of dataframe for plotting

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have the following dataframe as `df` in python:

```
Color     Blue     Red    Green   Yellow  Orange

 Zone
-------------------------------------------------
   1A      3.5     3.6      2.9      3.2     3.9
   2B      3.2     4.1      2.6      2.3     3.4
   3C      2.9     3.9      3.1      2.7     3.0
```

Previously I was able to produce a plot by simply running:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', color=['b', 'c', 'g', 'm', 'r'], sharey=True, legend=True, rot=True, zorder=1.6)
```

However, now running this line yields the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

Why might this error be occurring and how might I fix it?

Comment: maybe try ``df.plot(kind='bar', color=['b', 'c', 'g', 'm', 'r'], sharey=True, legend=True, rot=True, zorder=1.6)``? (basically just remove the ``_``)

Comment: Good suggestion there, though that was my fault just for writing "df_" instead of "df", but unfortunately the code still does not work.

Comment: Try to pd.to_numeric all your dataframe columns.   check your dypes.

Comment: @ScottBoston I just tried that using `pd.to_numeric(df.<insert_color>)` for each column, and then ran `df.dtypes` and it revealed that each column is `float64` and that `dytpe: object`. The same error message persists when I try to plot.

Comment: The best thing is to create some data that reproduces your error?   Show the dataframe creation code here.